# WFC Dataservices populate relations

Tags: windows-phone-7, wcf-data-services, odata

I need help with getting a list of persons with the list addresses (address is a property on Person)
from a WCF Dataservices to my WP7 app.

I got this method in a WCF DataServices, that get the data using EF

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<Person> GetPersonAdress(int id)
{
   return from p in CurrentDataSource.Persons.Include("Addresses")
          from a in c.Addresses
          where a.Field1 > 1
          where a.Field2 == id
          select p;
 }
```

and in my WP7 app, I got a DataServices class looking like this, where I call the method.
but it doesn´t work. BeginExecute exit out before BeginLoadProperty completes ...

```
public class DataServices : IDataServices
{
    public void LoadPersonAddress(Action<IEnumerable<Person>, Exception> callback, int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var queryString = string.Format("GetPersonAdress?id={0}", id);

            _context.BeginExecute<Person>(new Uri(queryString, UriKind.Relative), (ar =>
            {
                var ctx = ar.AsyncState as DBEntities;
                var persons = new List<Person>();

                var results = ctx.EndExecute<Person>(ar);

                foreach (var person in results)
                {
                    var newPerson = new Person
                    {
                        Id = person.Id,
                        FirstName = person.FirstName,
                        LastName = person.LastName,
                    };

                    ctx.BeginLoadProperty(person, "Adresses", (asb =>
                    {
                        ctx.EndLoadProperty(asb);

                    }), person);

                    persons.Add(newPerson);
                }
                callback(persons, null);

            }), _context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            callback(null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the Address list in a person populated ?

Comment: Just curious - why do you need to create a new instance of the Person object, why not just reuse the one returned by the query? Also note that given the code above, the "person" instance will get the Addresses once the LoadProperty is finished, but the "newPerson" will not, since it's a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
~/GetPersonAddress?id=12345&$expand=Addresses
```